# Adhoc Distribution iPhone Application !

Tags: iphone, xcode

When i click on the grey large button on xcode ( which we use to switch between simulator and device options ) . It doesnt have the distribution option. It only has debug and release options.
Can anybody tell me wats wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a Release configuration.  In your Project/Target inspector, go to Configurations tab, and create one.

Answer (score 0):

Use the release option with your distribution certificate, and create a provisioning profile with your App ID and device UUIDs.
Make sure to select the Ad Hoc option instead of the App Store option in the provisioning portal.